# I keep getting an error code "unable to write program user data" I can't even open the program visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

It says please make sure the following directories are writable.

```
/Applications/untitled folder/Library/ApplicationSupport/Code
/Applications/untitled folder/.vscode/extensions
```

what does it want me to do I am clueless?

Answer (score 2):

I am leaving this answer here because I had a-lot of trouble with this problem.

Steps:

1. `sudo chown -R username ~/.vscode/extensions`
2. `sudo chown -R username ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code`

Then you should be able to open vscode from the application folder.
To find out what your username is just type `whoami` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `C:\Users\Azox` and delete `.vscode`.
2. Go to `C:\Users\Azox\AppData\Roaming` and delete `Code`.